# I need Quick refresh data from firebase database when the data is add

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments

I just want to refresh the data as I enter the new data but my code is not working right it shows the data after reopen the same activity.

**Here is my code:**

```
Total_bgt_dataref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
            Map<String, Object> objectMap=(HashMap<String, Object>)snapshot.getValue();
            String value=(String)objectMap.get("Total_Budget");
            tv_budget.setText(value);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"DatabaseError Total Budget",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: which design pattern you are using like MVC, MVP or MVVM

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` user `addValueEventListener`, Since `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` will be canceled once an event listened, but `addValueEventListener` will always listen to the value change event.

```
Total_bgt_dataref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener(){
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot){
        for(DataSnapshot ds:snapshot.getChildren()){
            Map<String, Object> objectMap=(HashMap<String, Object>)snapshot.getValue();
            String value=(String)objectMap.get("Total_Budget");
            tv_budget.setText(value);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"DatabaseError Total Budget",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
});
```

check [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Query#public-valueeventlistener-addvalueeventlistener-valueeventlistener-listener) for more information.

Note: You must remove the listener once you are done with it, so you must keep the reference to the listener and remove it at the end.